Questions about Anabin database and statement of comparability for Opportunity card
I have a Master’s Degree, MLISc (16 years) education, then MPhil in Library and Information Science and then PhD in Library and Information Science.
Librarianship is a regulated profession in Germany. My degrees are listed in the anabin database. Now I am seeking opportunity card (Chancenkarte) for Germany.
My question is whether I have to apply for three statements of comparability in Germany for above three degrees or one MLIS only?

What did the Consular Services Portal help team say when you asked them?

Librarian is a regulated profession? Are you sure? Usually professions posing a significant danger to the general public or individual in case of malpractice are regulated (e. g. lawyer, medical doctor, or teacher [at a state‑run school]). Now there isn’t really a danger of harming people if you do your job as a librarian poorly, is it? You may need to prove your university degree in case you want to join public service (in particular gehobener Dienst) but there is usually the option to work as a regular employee (Angestellter).

@KaiBurghardt is correct as far as I can tell. Librarianship is not listed as regulated on the official portal. The profession may be ‘regulated’ by eg an official association for qualified librarians but that’s not the same thing.

I’m voting to close this question because librarianship is not a regulated profession so the question is not relevant.
